# Prefill fields CodeIgniter class

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, class

I'm creating controllers in CodeIgniter which need to store some settings in the database.
Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
public function index()
{
    $config["function"] = __FUNCTION__;
    $config["class"]    = __CLASS__;
    $config["page"]     = "homepage";
    $this->core->initialize($config);
}
```

In the Core library these configurations get saved.
As you see I use PHP's __ FUNCTION __ and __ CLASS __ to have them stored into $config.

Is there a way to automate this process? So that everytime I create a new controller, the fields $config["class"] & $config["function"] are filled in automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could try extending the `CI_Controller` and make you own like this & put it in the `application/core/` directory:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $config["function"] = __FUNCTION__;
        $config["class"]    = __CLASS__;
        $config["page"]     = "homepage";
        $this->core->initialize($config);

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then each of your controllers would extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`, like this:

```
class ExampleController extends MY_Controller
{
    //if you have your own __construct method you need to
    //make sure that parent::__construct(); is present
    function __construct()
    {
        //other code...

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

You can read up about extending the CI Core Classes at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Good luck with your project

**----------EDIT---------**

I'm not sure that `$this->core` will correctly work since there is nothing that is setting this var in your example. You may need to set that in the `ExampleController` class.